# Intent.putExtras() just return null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick

I'm trying to send the intent.putString to other class but it's not working I don't know why

```
trigger.setOnClickListener( v-> {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("params", "okay");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    //finishAffinity();
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);

});
```

when the button clicked I send bundle to mainActivity

and I get message from mainactivity oncreate.

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

       if(extras != null ) {
           String _getData = extras.getString("param1");
           Log.i(TAG, "face detect message " + _getData);
       }
```

but I can't get any message on MainActivity.
plz give me some answer

Comment: you've set key as params but while calling it you're using param1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should aware that bundle is using key value pair, so if you create

```
bundle.putString("params", "okay");
```

the key is `params` and value is `okay`

And to get the value you should use the same key.

```
String _getData = extras.getString("params");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your params key in the Bundle. Like Below

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null ) {
   String _getData = extras.getString("params");
   Log.i(TAG, "face detect message " + _getData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this in your MainActivity class :

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

   if(extras != null ) {
       String _getData = extras.getString("params");
       Log.i(TAG, "face detect message " + _getData);
   }
```